# Having a hourly/weekly/etc... notification reminder (with AlarmManager?)

Tags: java, android, notifications, alarmmanager

I've looked almost everywhere! I can't find any help or tutorials or examples of making a notification trigger weekly, or hourly, or monthly. I heard some things about using AlarmManager, but I can't get it working.

I haven't worked with Java much (more of an objective-c guy) but I'm having some trouble with this notification system. Basically I just want to have a button that when I toggle on will notify the user every week to re-open the app (for example). And to trigger off of course when they don't want to be notified every week to 'open the app.' Anyway, any ideas? I've figured out how to get a notification in general to come up, but I can't get it to delay, or to happen when the app isn't open.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    // 8 AM Each day 
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, new Intent(context, MyClass.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);
```

This will fire alarm at 8AM each day. Similarly you can set alarm for any day you like.

**TO GET NOTIFICATION :**

```
  NotificationManager nm;
  nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);        
  CharSequence from = "VIPUL";
  CharSequence message = "Crazy About Android...";
  PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
    new Intent(), 0);
  Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,
    "Crazy About Android...", System.currentTimeMillis());
  notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
  nm.notify(1, notif);
```

You have to write this on the activity which you calling from alarm manager. This will show you notification.

You can also set a pending intent which will be called when user click on notification.

Comment: Can that fire a notification or just open the app at 8am?

Comment: So would I need to put the notification system in another class? or can it just do PendingIntent pi = PendingInt.getService(context,0,new Intent(context, createNotification()), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);? and I'm assuming this all runs in the background even if the application is closed?

Comment: You need to put notification code in the class which you are calling from alarm manager, so when alarm triggered, notification code will execute and show notification. So just put notification code simply in the onCreate method of the class which you are calling from AlarmManager.

Comment: @VipulPurohit can you please tell me how we will set if we want to trigger it at  8pm

Comment: @SreedevR : You can use something like this :: 

setRepeating(int type, Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()+(#YOUR_TIME_IN_MILLISECONDS#),  AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi)

Comment: if it helps anyone, you can add an ID if you want more than 1 alarm:
`PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
    new Intent(), 0);`
`PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 1,
    new Intent(), 0);`
`PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 2,
    new Intent(), 0);`

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you need to take a look at the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) class and especially on its [setRepeating()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) method. It allows you to set an interval for triggering the action. Hope this helps.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out how to use AlarmManager with an alert and actually work. I have been googling for hours and can't find a tutorial that actually works that isn't just a normal alarm clock, but works with notifications. Thank you for the help, I will look into the setRepeating() method, but do you know any tutorials for the AlarmManager with Notifications?

Comment: @SpencerPeriShulem, Sorry, haven't read any tutorials, but I know that this topic is described properly in the Pro Android series of books, you should consider getting yourself one.